# Error MySQL said: Documentation Cannot connect: invalid settings. [Ubuntu]

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, xampp

hello All I've facing some difficult problem ...
i just tried all solution hare are given but won't work :( 
what should i do

Welcome to phpMyAdmin

Error

MySQL said: Documentation
Cannot connect: invalid settings.
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i just find appropriate solution for this problem ..
just nothing 
step 1. ensure that  there are no duplicate file here like extra phpmyadmin or php version don't exist with each other 
step 2. total remove if there are another server exist...
step 3 .if fully remove all thing then again install a server 
hope it won't be show this warring....
enjoy